# How to output a table as a parquet file in spark-sql, not spark-shell?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It is easy to read a table from CSV file using `spark-sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    X   STRING,
    Y   STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = "\,",
    "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'input.csv' INTO TABLE MyTable;
```

But how can I output this result as Parquet file?

PS: I know how to do that in `spark-shell`, but it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: do you mean *writing* this to a table in parquet format?

Comment: No, I mean into a parquet file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create one table with the schema of your results in hive stored as parquet. After getting the results you can export them into the parquet file format table like this.

`set hive.insert.into.external.tables = true`

`create external table mytable_parq ( use your source table DDL) stored as parquet location '/hadoop/mytable';`

`insert into mytable_parq select * from mytable ;`

or

```
insert overwrite directory '/hadoop/mytable' STORED AS PARQUET select * from MyTable ;
```

Comment: I've tried that and it failed. Could you please provide a full listing? Where can I specify output file name?

Comment: Error: `missing 'TABLE' at 'directory'`
I've seen this statement but it looks like this is not spark-sql.

Comment: Yes, it was from the 2nd query - "insert overwrite directory"

Comment: you have to prepare one table for your parquet file then write the data into it. check the updated code.